# PostgreSQL on Mac SELECT does nothing

Tags: node.js, macos, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL on my Mac (OS 10.10.3) from the main site. I just downloaded the .app file and ran it from Applications. I also added psql to $PATH.

I created a db called todo. I inserted (through curl and a node.js file) data into that db, and when I try to select all from that table nothing happens at all.

Here I see that it's definitely entering data because it's returning it via this code:

```
// SQL Query > Select Data
    var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC");

    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', function(row) {
        results.push(row);
    });
```

[image]

Here nothing happens when typing "select * from items"

[image]

I'm wondering if maybe there's a permissions problem or something. Maybe the user I'm connecting to psql with isn't a superuser? It's the same user I installed PostgreSQL with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select * from items;`

Make sure to use semicolon at the end of your statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the line.